# How to auto dial 9+Number on Cisco 7941 redial?

Tags: cisco, voip

Is it possible to set up a Cisco 7941 phone to dial 9 before the redial number?

When I view missed calls, and try to redial one of the numbers, it always fails because it doesn't dial 9 first.  I have to write the number down and then manually dial the 9 and then the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  If you go to missed calls, you need to select the number you want to call back and then click the EditDial button on the phone. That will allow you to add a 9 before the number you are calling back.

Comment: Done this before... can't remember exactly how... I think we have it translate the number as it's coming in to add a 9.  That way it will show up in the missed calls log as 912345678901